# Costum, code generated buttons and forms, and linking them together in C#

Tags: c#, forms, button, dynamic-linking

## Hello Everyone

In the following, I am going to give you a routh idea of what I am trying to accomplish with the program I am trying to code at the moment bevor describing the problem I am struggeling to solve. Thanks for your help!

### The Program

#### Purpose

Timers. Multiple of them. Each timer should be displayed on an individual form, being controlled by individual buttons and having a unique design, once again set up by user settings.

#### Layout

The program itself should be made up by one main form, containing all "start" and "stop" buttons for each timer. However, the timer forms should be open at all time. Meaning, once the user has changed the properties, all timer forms should be closed again and depending on the settings new forms should open.

### Question

In generell, I know how to open a form in such a way to change properties and componants from another form. Example:

```
namespace example
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form2 timerForm1;

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            timerForm1 = new Form();
            timerForm1.Show();
        }

        //now you are able to access Form2 in different functions, like:
        {
            timerForm1.label1.Text = "00:02:56";
        }
    }
}
```

However, I need to open as many forms as the user declares, meaning I can not set up variables in fore hand. However, I need to access those opend forms just like in the given example.

I would like to store the different, user declared timers inside an array or list if possible, if there is a smarter, easier or faster way i can adapt and change it to whatever is required to get it working.

Comment: Look into List<T> here maybe List<Form> or List<yourTimerFormClass> !

Answer (score 0):

I didn't really understand what or if you have an issue with the timers. But controlling various amount of forms from each individual is not that hard.

As I understand that you want to control various amount of Form2 instances from one Form1. In that case you can make a List of Form2 and add each Form2 you creat to that list.

Comment: now heres the problem with you answer: if i try to refer to one of those set up Forms it shows me an "this variable is not aviable" error. And i dont know how to refer to a specific Form of those multiple ones i made with the same name.

Comment: @Sepheraton would you mind sharing how you implemented the list? cause the problem you got didn't happen to me... And if you want to recognize each form you can give them some sort of an ID field that will be different in each form. I can't think of other ways to implement unknown amount of forms without a list...